# Assembler gcc : undefined reference to puts

Tags: gcc, assembly

i am learning the assembler langage and i tried to compile my program with gcc but it displays an error message:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -lc test.o -o test
test.o: In function `_start':
test.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `puts'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code:

```
BITS 32

 EXTERN puts

 SECTION .data
 chaine      db "Hello world !", 0

 SECTION .text
    GLOBAL _start

    _start:
    push dword chaine
    call puts
    add esp, 4
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: It still displays this error: test.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_puts'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Are you using OS X?  Linux doesn't prefix symbols with `_`.  Or maybe you're just confusing gcc: try `gcc -nostartfiles`, rather than trying to tell it two opposite things with `-nostdlib -lc`.  You can also use `gcc -v` to dump the command lines of the internal commands gcc uses.

Comment: Can you try my program in the answer and see what the output is?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 64 bits 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lc` *before* `test.o` is the problem.  The reference to an undefined `puts` is only seen after the linker is done looking at `libc.so`.

A much better way to do what you're probably trying to achieve is: `gcc -nostartfiles` instead.  That worked for me, with your source, on Linux.  Using `-nostdlib foo.o -lc` does work for me, but skips `libgcc`.  This probably doesn't matter if you aren't linking any code generated by gcc.  If you are, there might be function calls to stuff like the helper function for 64bit division on 32bit machines.

Comment: I've just reproduced the problem and your solution on OpenSuSE. The problem is not with the ordering of `-l` flags within the command-line; I've tried `-nostdlib` and `-lc` before and after `test.o`, and both cases compile to a `./test` with the same size and MD5 hash. Having still never seen a sequence of object files and linker flags that cannot link given a particular ordering of `-l` flags but can under another, this notion of library flag ordering remains a mystifying myth for me. If this isn't an urban legend, where does it come from?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: I just double-checked (with gcc 5.2.1 on x86-64 Ubuntu 15.10):  `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -v test.o -o test  -lc` links.  `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -lc -v test.o -o test` **fails**, with the exact error message from the question.  gcc uses `collect2` instead of running `ld` directly, which might make a difference, or be a choice that Ubuntu makes diff. from OpenSUSE.  Your point that it never matters what order libraries are listed sounds familiar.  I'm partly guessing about the actual reason (first paragraph).  Is there some other explanation for our observed behaviour?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Where the libraries are placed can make difference when you are linking against static libraries. LD will attempt to resolve things in order. If you have an object that needs something that can't be resolved it queues it up. If it hits a library on the command line that resolves it, it loads only what is needed (not whole thing) and continues as if the library was never encountered. If another object listed after needs something from that same library it won't get resolved because LD no longer knows about the library.Putting libraries at the end prevents this scenario

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Oh also, "where does it come from?": back in the bad old days, I think linkers "forgot about" libraries after resolving any currently-unresolved symbols from them.  So you actually did need to list libraries in dependency order.  Back in the really bad old days, you apparently even needed to sort object files *within* a library in dependency order when creating it.  See the ["`tsort` Background" info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tsort-background.html).

Comment: Those were some bad old days indeed! For my part, I looked at the patches that ship inside [OpenSuSE's gcc src rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/leap/42.1/repo/oss/suse/src/gcc48-4.8.5-16.7.src.rpm). None of them seem to relate to link order. @MichaelPetch This is only a static-link issue then? That may explain it; This particular idea would be momentum from the time when static linking was more popular and computers/linkers couldn't afford to do random-access reads, as tape archives are a very sequential medium. I prefer the mental simplicity of order-invariant linking.

Answer (score 3):

Your original program will work:

```
BITS 32

EXTERN puts

SECTION .data
chaine      db "Hello world !", 0

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start

_start:
push dword chaine
call puts
add esp, 4
mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

But you need to compile with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.o -o test -lc` (Yes -lc needs to be at the end) after `nasm -felf test.asm`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the OP's question.  Defining `main`, instead of `_start`, is a different beast.  Although if this failed for the OP, it would tell us he was on a platform where he needed `_puts` or something.  However, I just tried my theory, and `-nostdlib -lc` was the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Editted.

Comment: Well spotted, right of course libraries have to come last.